# I want to overRide json Object depending on dropDown selected value

Tags: asp.net, .net, arrays, json, angularjs

This is my html Code

```
<select style="width:100px;" data-nodrag ng-model="conditions" ng-change="changingCondition(this)">
    <option value="and">and</option>
    <option value="or">or</option>
</select>
```

and this is my `ng-change` code that i tried but it is not working, if i have multiple "and"'s it will change all of them to "or", this should not happen

```
$scope.changingCondition = function (scope) {
    var cond = $scope.conditions
    //var jsonstr = JSON.stringify($scope.data);
    //var new_jsonstr = jsonstr.replace("and", "or");

    var obj = JSON.parse($scope.data)[0];
    obj.cond = obj.and;
    delete obj.cond;
}
```

This is my jsonObject

```
    [{
        "and": [{
            "fieldName": "",
                "value": "",
                "condition": ""
        }]
    }];
```

If is select "or" the jSonObject should  overRide to "or" from "and" and if i againg change it to "and" it should be "and"

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to change `and` property to `or`when "or" is selected and viceversa?

Comment: @Michelem yes  i want to change or if the selected value is or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still can't understand exactly what you want but try this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/54ozw729/1)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select style="width:100px;" data-nodrag ng-model="conditions" ng-change="changingCondition()">
        <option value="and">and</option>
        <option value="or">or</option>
    </select>
    {{data}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.changingCondition = function () {
        $scope.data = [{
            "and": [{
                "fieldName": "",
                    "value": "",
                    "condition": ""
            }]
        }];

        if ($scope.conditions === 'or') {
            $scope.data[0].or = $scope.data[0].and;
            delete $scope.data[0].and;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, This is wat i wanted exactly :)

Comment: Nice one.. Can u help me in this pls http://stackoverflow.com/q/31560652/5071852

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you want to achieve, but the noticeable problem is that your code sets the literal property `"cond"` instead of the value of `$scope.conditions`. You need to access the property using `obj[cond]`. Here is an example [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/y8VrnkChRso6sCCCge8I?p=preview).